# How to copy a folder on a USB device to my iPad

Tags: ipad, usb

I have a [Kingston DataTraveller 80 USB flash drive](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08C9KMC2M/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and on there I have a folder with some videos.

I also have an iPad Pro 12.9 (5th generation).

I want to copy the directory on my flash drive to my iPad.  These are the steps I am taking:

1. In Files select KINGSTON under Location.
2. Select folder named OTI, then click Copy.
3. Under Locations now select On My iPad.
4. clicked on a directory, was named tennis, which opened that directory.
5. Pressed in that directory and the only options I get are New Folder, Scan Documents, Get Info.

I was expecting to see a Paste option.

What am I doing wrong?

Some additional information. If I press then select New Folder in the OTI folder on the USB drive, I immediately get error: The file "untitled folder" couldn't be save in the folder "OTI"

If I try to copy the other way round, eg select a file on my iPad, I selected a photo, select Copy, then got to USB drive OTI folder and press, I DO get a paste option, but if I select it I get:  The Operation Can't be Completed error.  Couldn't communicate with a helper application.

How can I get copying from the flash drive to my iPad to work?

...

Update, I have no idea why, but just tried to do this procedure just now and it is now working!  I really didn't imagine it!

Comment: Is it a folder you created yourself? If you open Numbers (or another app) and try to create a file in that folder, does it work?

Comment: hmmm, if I press then select New Folder in the OTI folder on the USB drive, I immediately get error: The file "untitled folder" couldn't be save in the folder "OTI".

Comment: Missing write permissions in the source folder shouldn't be a problem, but can you create a folder within the target folder (`tennis`)?

Comment: I can create a folder within tennis folder on iPad.  I can also create a folder in OTI folder on USB drive - although it is slower.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried again to copy the OTI folder, and now it is working. wtf!